# V-Link Roland Midi protocol

Tags: protocols, midi, manual

I'm looking for the manual describing the protocol of the Roland V-Link MIDI that was opened. 
Does anyone know where I can find? 
I wrote to Roland but I had no answers.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V-Link is just a bunch of standard MIDI messages.  CC and the like.

If you dig up the manual for one of their video synthesizers, there is a great list of the MIDI spec.  Most Roland products have this.  I recommend getting started there.

http://lib.roland.co.jp/support/en/manuals/res/1811303/CG-8_MIDI_Imple_e2.pdf